# Understanding generator functions in ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, ecmascript-6

I am trying to wrap my head around JS generators but I don't understand why the sample async operations below return undefined.

I thought the whole point of the yield was to wait for async calls to complete.

```js
function getUsers(){
 var users;
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'
 }).then(function(users) {
   console.log(gen.next(users));
 });
 
}

function getPosts(){
 var posts;
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'
 }).then(function(posts) {
   console.log(gen.next(posts));
 });
}

function getComments(){
 var comments;
 $.ajax({
   url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/'
 }).then(function(comments) {
   console.log(gen.next(comments));
 });
}

function* myGenerator() {
 var users = yield getUsers();
 var posts = yield getPosts();
 var comments = yield getComments();
 return ([users, posts, comments]);
}

var gen = myGenerator();
gen.next();

// {value: undefined, done: false}  ---> why undefined here?
// {value: undefined, done: false}  ---> why undefined here?
// {value: Array(3), done: true}    ---> YAY, array DOES contains expected data
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone shine some light on that? Thank you!

Comment: For starters, you're not returning anything from your functions. (returning inside `then()` isn't the same thing.

Comment: As mentioned, you can't return from an ajax function, you need to call another function, typically called a callback function, or in the world of Promises, you need to call `resolve` or `reject`

Comment: Thank you @Mark_M and for your comment. I have edited the code above to try and chain the different steps together passing the returned data back to the generator. It works as expected, but the first two yield statements are still returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the edit things work a little different. In every case except the last, your generator is yielding the result of your function which is undefined because your functions don't return anything.

However, when you call `next()` from inside the the `then()`s you are passing the result of the ajax promise to the generator. The generator receives that value, and save it in a variable (`users`, `posts`, etc). But it still returns undefined because the value of  `yield getPosts()` is undefined since the function doesn't return anything.

The last call to `next()` happens in the `then()` of `getComments()`. Now the generator is out of values, so it returns `{done: true}` and the values you have asynchronously been putting in variables. It returns those and your done.

This would all be much easier if you just did:

```
function getUsers(){
    return $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'
    })
}

getUsers().then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand and I am starting to see how this could be useful. I wrapped getUsers in a promise and get the expected value now! Thank you guys.

```js
function getUsers(){
 return new Promise((resolve) => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'
  }).then(function(users) {
    resolve(gen.next(users));
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` already returns a promise. You can just return that. (i.e. `return $.ajax({/*...etc*/})` )